# Retrieving individually polygon information from Google Fusion Tables

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I'm using the following example to be able to use a (false) mouse over event in Fusion tables. It's actually working, as it is. However the click event is not working as I'd like (it's inside the `drawMap` function)

The issue occurs in the following line of code:

```
infowindow.setContent(rows[i][7]);
```

I want to retrieve the information of the column 8 called "Nome_Reg" (index 7), for each polygon when it's clicked.

Each polygon has a different attribute for this column. However, the way I'm doing it's return only the information for the last polygon drawn and not from the polygons individually.

Do you have a hint why is it not working?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Regions</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #map {
            height: 100%;
        }
        #info-box {
            background-color: white;
            border: 1px solid black;
            bottom: 30px;
            height: 20px;
            padding: 10px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 30px;
        }
    </style>

    <!-- loading Jquery file -->
    <script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39041929/site/MapaTravessia/Includes/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        //Loading JQuery
        $(document).ready(function(){

            var map;
            var infowindow;

            var Regions;

        });

        function initMap() {    

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { zoom: 10, center: {lat: -18.92990560776172 , lng: -43.4406814550781},}); 

            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({maxWidth: 300});

            // Initialize JSONP request
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            var url = ['https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v2/query?'];
            url.push('sql=');
            var query = 'SELECT * FROM ' +
            '16lyNB62unqHuH3fh94lHGDrGEwQVTztRIzm_DWsf';
            var encodedQuery = encodeURIComponent(query);
            url.push(encodedQuery);
            url.push('&callback=drawMap');  //Calls the drawMap function
            url.push('&key=AIzaSyCoC9A3WgFneccRufbysInygnWrhCie-T0');
            script.src = url.join('');
            var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
            body.appendChild(script);
        }


        function drawMap(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var rows = data['rows'];
            for (var i in rows) {
                var newCoordinates = [];
                var geometries = data['rows'][i][0]['geometries'];
                if (geometries) {
                  for (var j in geometries) {
                    newCoordinates.push(constructNewCoordinates(geometries[j]));
                  }
                } else {
                  newCoordinates = constructNewCoordinates(rows[i][0]['geometry']);
                }

                var colors = ['#AF4604', '#AF8A04', '#037158']; 
                var ColorReceived;
                if (rows[i][5] == 'CMD') ColorReceived = 0;
                if (rows[i][5] == 'AM') ColorReceived = 1;
                if (rows[i][5] == 'DJ') ColorReceived = 2;

                Regions = new google.maps.Polygon({
                  paths: newCoordinates,
                  strokeColor: colors[ColorReceived],
                  strokeOpacity: 1,
                  strokeWeight: 1,
                  fillColor: colors[ColorReceived],
                  fillOpacity: 0.5
                });

                //Working Mouseover event
                google.maps.event.addListener(Regions, 'mouseover', function() {
                    this.setOptions({strokeWeight: 3});
                });
                //Working Mouseout event
                google.maps.event.addListener(Regions, 'mouseout', function() {
                    this.setOptions({strokeWeight: 1});
                });

                //NOT WORKING CLICK EVENT 
                google.maps.event.addListener(Regions, 'click', function (event) {
                    infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
                    infowindow.setContent(rows[i][7]);
                    infowindow.open(map);

                });

                Regions.setMap(map);
            }

        }

        //access the lat and long for each node and return a array containing those values, extracted from fusion table.
        function constructNewCoordinates(polygon) {
            var newCoordinates = [];
            var coordinates = polygon['coordinates'][0];
            for (var i in coordinates) {
              newCoordinates.push(
                // write the lat and long respectively
                  new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[i][1], coordinates[i][0]));
            }
            return newCoordinates;
        }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script async defer
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBFYwb6-B6u2cs5oknTRwtfBng2kgdDMgk&callback=initMap">
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add the `click`-listener to the Polygon, not to the FusionTablesLayer(only there `event.row` is available).

**Possible solution:**

In the loop create  Polygon-property where you store the particular row and access this property in the click-handler

```js
//Loading JQuery
        $(document).ready(function(){

            var map;
            var infowindow;

            var Regions;

        });

        function initMap() {    

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { zoom: 9, center: {lat: -18.92990560776172 , lng: -43.4406814550781},}); 

            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({maxWidth: 300});

            // Initialize JSONP request
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            var url = ['https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v2/query?'];
            url.push('sql=');
            var query = 'SELECT * FROM ' +
            '16lyNB62unqHuH3fh94lHGDrGEwQVTztRIzm_DWsf';
            var encodedQuery = encodeURIComponent(query);
            url.push(encodedQuery);
            url.push('&callback=drawMap');  //Calls the drawMap function
            url.push('&key=AIzaSyCoC9A3WgFneccRufbysInygnWrhCie-T0');
            script.src = url.join('');
            var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
            body.appendChild(script);
        }


        function drawMap(data) {
            var rows = data['rows'];
            for (var i in rows) {
                var newCoordinates = [];
                var geometries = data['rows'][i][0]['geometries'];
                if (geometries) {
                  for (var j in geometries) {
                    newCoordinates.push(constructNewCoordinates(geometries[j]));
                  }
                } else {
                  newCoordinates = constructNewCoordinates(rows[i][0]['geometry']);
                }

                var colors = ['#AF4604', '#AF8A04', '#037158']; 
                var ColorReceived;
                if (rows[i][5] == 'CMD') ColorReceived = 0;
                if (rows[i][5] == 'AM') ColorReceived = 1;
                if (rows[i][5] == 'DJ') ColorReceived = 2;

                Regions = new google.maps.Polygon({
                  paths: newCoordinates,
                  strokeColor: colors[ColorReceived],
                  strokeOpacity: 1,
                  strokeWeight: 1,
                  fillColor: colors[ColorReceived],
                  fillOpacity: 0.5,
                  row: (function(index){
                          var row={};
                          for(var j=0;j<data['rows'][index].length;++j){
                            row[data.columns[j]]=data['rows'][index][j];
                          }
                          return row;
                        })(i)
                });

                //Working Mouseover event
                google.maps.event.addListener(Regions, 'mouseover', function() {
                    this.setOptions({strokeWeight: 3});
                });
                //Working Mouseout event
                google.maps.event.addListener(Regions, 'mouseout', function() {
                    this.setOptions({strokeWeight: 1});
                });

                
               
                // Working click event
                
                google.maps.event.addListener(Regions, 'click', function (event) {
                     var Content = this.row['Nome_Reg'];
                    infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
                    infowindow.setContent(Content);
                    infowindow.open(map);

                });
                
                
                
                 

                

                Regions.setMap(map);
            }

        }

        //access the lat and long for each node and return a array containing those values, extracted from fusion table.
        function constructNewCoordinates(polygon) {
            var newCoordinates = [];
            var coordinates = polygon['coordinates'][0];
            for (var i in coordinates) {
              newCoordinates.push(
                // write the lat and long respectively
                  new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[i][1], coordinates[i][0]));
            }
            return newCoordinates;
        }
```

```css
html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #map {
            height: 100%;
        }
        #info-box {
            background-color: white;
            border: 1px solid black;
            bottom: 30px;
            height: 20px;
            padding: 10px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 30px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
        <script async defer
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
        </script>
```